# Show that $\vec{BB_1}=\vec{AA_1}+\vec{CC_1}$

Tags: geometry, vectors

$DABC$ and $DA_1B_1C_1$ are parallelograms. Show that $$\vec{BB_1}=\vec{AA_1}+\color{red}{\vec{CC_1}}$$

[image]

I noted that $$\vec{BB_1}=\vec{BA}+\vec{AA_1}+\vec{A_1B_1}\\\vec{BB_1}=\vec{BC_1}+\vec{C_1B_1}=\vec{BC}+\color{red}{\vec{CC_1}}+\vec{C_1B_1}$$
but nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

$\overrightarrow{BB_1}=\overrightarrow{BA}+\overrightarrow{A A_1}+\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}$

Then $\overrightarrow{A_1B_1} = \overrightarrow{DC_1}$ because $AB_1DC_1$ is a parallelogram. Moreover $\overrightarrow{BA}= \overrightarrow{CD}$ therefore :

$$ \overrightarrow{BB_1} = \overrightarrow{CD}+\overrightarrow{DC_1}+\overrightarrow{AA_1} = \overrightarrow{CC_1}+\overrightarrow{AA_1} $$

Answer (score 0):

$\vec{BB_1}=\vec{BA}+\vec{AA_1}+\vec{A_1D}+\vec{DC}+\vec{CC_1}+\vec{C_1B_1}$

Then use that the following sums are zero and cancel each other (opposite vectors):

$\vec{BA}+\vec{DC}=0$

$\vec{A_1D}+\vec{C_1B_1}=0$